# Bot discord ayuda

Tags: javascript

tengo este codigo javascript(Bot discord) que lo que que quiero que haga esque repita lo que escribo una sola vez pero no consigo como hacerlo, y se repite muchas veces :(

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const  client = new Discord.Client();

client.on("ready", () => {
   console.log("Estoy listo!");
});


client.on("message", (message) => {


  if (message.channel.send('',+message)) {
  message.channel.send('https://todocodigos.000webhostapp.com/twitter/banner.php?banner=' + message);
  




  }
  

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Por lo que he entendido, quieres que el **Bot** repita exactamente lo que tu escribas en el canal de discord.

El principal fallo por el cual tu mensaje se repite sin parar, es porque el bot está escuchando todos los mensajes que son mandados a ese canal (incluidos los mensajes del propio bot), es decir que cada vez que el bot responde a tu mensaje, el se responde a si mismo y esto crea un bucle que no acaba.

Otro fallo es que lo que obtienes del metodo `on('message')` no es un string, obtienes una clase del tipo **Message** con información sobre le mensaje, tales como, el autor, el contenido del mensaje, la guild desde la que ha sido enviada etc...

#### La clase Message: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message

La manera de solucionar eso es añadiendo esto a tu código:

```
client.on('message', (message) => {
    // En caso de que el mensaje proceda del BOT no seguiremos con la ejecución del código
    if(message.author.bot) return;

    message.channel.send(message.content)
}
```

Basicamente `msg.author.bot` es un **boolean** que devuelve true si el mensaje a sido enviado por el bot, de esta manera evitas que el bot se responda a si mismo.

Answer (score 0):

Estimado,

Puedo ayudarte en el primer evento

```
client.on("ready", () => {
   console.log("Estoy listo!");
});
```

En este caso de lenguaje de JS, este evento solo necesita ser leído una vez, en el momento de conectarse, luego lo correcto es que el evento sea de esta manera:

```
client.once("ready", () => {
   console.log("Estoy listo!");
});
```

Saludos